# How to watch reference variables using CUDA Parallel NSight debugger?

Tags: c++, reference, cuda, visual-studio-debugging, nsight

I can properly watch any variable or pointer but cannot do it for reference variables when debugging with NSight. I have already tried to convert the reference to pointer in the watch or immediate windows but no avail. I don't want to rewrite my code using pointers. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 in a Windows 7 64 bits machine, CUDA 4.0, Parallel NSight 2.0 and my code is compiling for Win32.

Example:
    __ device__ void function(int& parameter)

Cannot debug parameter. It is unreachable by debugger.

Comment: Are you referring to a C++ reference?

Comment: Yes. Example: "__ device __ void function(int &parameter)". Cannot debug parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to Nsight 2.2, CUDA 4.2 and Dev driver 301.32 and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced the issue on my machine. Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010, CUDA 4.1.

I can't debug:

```
__device__ int myfunc(int& myint)
{
  return myint * 5;
}
```

I can set a breakpoint on the line with the `return`, but I can't view the variable because it was passed by reference.

If I change it to:

```
__device__ int myfunc(int& myint)
{
  int debug(myint);
  return debug * 5;
}
```

I can view the `debug` variable.

I think you should submit a bug to NVIDIA. I don't know if their system has recovered enough for that yet though.

Comment: I still cannot watch the variable with this method.

Comment: Are you using the `debug` variable? Unfortunately, it's not enough to copy the variable that was passed by reference into it. So the second example is `debug * 5` rather than `myint * 5`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated to Nsight 2.2, CUDA 4.2 and Dev driver 301.32 and it did the trick.